Why does measuring the $X$ stabilisers at the boundary for rough merging give $X_{L}X_{L}$
In the paper Surface code quantum computing by lattice surgery, for rough merging, they state that measuring the $X$ stabilisers at the boundary is equivalent to $X_{L}X_{L}$.
What I don't understand is what the new $X$ stabiliser measurements spanning the old boundary are meant to be. and how they're product gives these logical operators.
Do they mean that, using the 3 pink data qubits, they construct 3 new $X$ stabilizer measurements, and then the product of those 3 stabilizers would be equivalent to 2 logical $X$ operators running parallel to the old boundary? If this is the case, then why would the rounds of error correction we do on both the 3 qubits and 2 surfaces allow us to somehow arrive at this
If they are taking the existing $X$ stabilisers, then I don't see how the product of them even givens you the product of the 2 logical $X$ operators of each surface, given they act on different qubits, unless the idea is that the data qubits in the boundaries of the lattice disappear.


The $X$ stabilizers to be measured are the ones indicated. You have two three-qubit stabilizers at the top and bottom and two four-qubit stabilizers. 
Note that each pink qubit is acted on by two stabilizer measurements. Hence that the product of all these stabilizers is equal to two columns of $X$ measurements, one on the rightmost column of the left patch and  one on the leftmost column of the right patch. This is the measurement $X_LX_L$.

Thank you for your answer. Ok so it was my first guess. But how does the measurement actually give us $X_{L}X_{L}$? As in my question, I can clearly see that the product of the operators of the stabilisers will indeed give the product of those two logical operators. But the measurement of stabilisers doesn't cancel overlapping operators in the same way the product does.

ie if I measure those 4 stabilisers, it will collapse the two surfaces into an eigenstate of the 4 of them. But that wouldn't be the same as just measuring the logical operators, and the eigenstate in question wouldn't even be a +1 eigenstate, correct?

You get the four individual outcomes of $\pm 1$ for each stabilizer (these are indeed random) but the product of those four outcomes is the same as the outcome of the observable $X_LX_L$ which may or may not be random depending on the joint state of the two patches.

As for your first comment, consider measuring two Pauli observables $P_1, P_2$ and obtaining $+1$ for both or $-1$ for both (i.e. the product is $+1$). This means that you apply the projector $\frac{1+P_1}{2}\frac{1+P_2}{2} + \frac{1-P_1}{2}\frac{1-P_2}{2} = \frac{1 + P_1P_2}{2}$ on the state. Replace $P_i$ with the stabilizers here to see why you can ignore the $X$ operations on the pink qubits.

OK so I understand that, since the application of these 4 stabilisers gives the logical state of the surface code weighted by $(-1)^{s_{1}s_{2}s_{3}s_{4}}$, which means that, given $X_{L}X_{L}$ is equal to the product of these stabilisers, the logical state is a $(-1)^{s_{1}s_{2}s_{3}s_{4}}$ eigenstate of $X_{L}X_{L}$ as well. But what is that measurement formalism you used that shows we can ignore the middle qubits?

They are still part of the overall surface code, correct? I mean the new merged surface will have them present where the old boundary was, so why would we be able to ignore them? I'm not sure what notation you have used to express the outcome of the projector that is applied tbh, as now, looking at it, I fail to see how we couldn't just ignore a large amount of qubits in a stabiliser code, as we could derive projectors that would ignore many of them taking the approach above, ie any qubits the stabiliser measurments share.

If you know the outcomes of the observable $X_1X_2$ and the observable $X_2X_3$, you also know the outcome of the product of those two observables which is $X_1X_3$. You have "ignored" the second qubit here because $X_2^2 = I$. Similarly here, you know the outcomes of the stabilizer measurements so you also know the outcome of the observable constructed by their products, which is $X_LX_L$.

So the new joint state of the two patches of the planar code is in a $(-1)^{S_{1},S_{2},S_{3},S_{4}}$ eigenstate of $X_{L}X_{L}$, given the product of the stabilisers. This much makes sense to me. But it will also be an eigenstate of the 4 new stabilisers, with the results the measurments returned, yes? As in those 3 qubits are now part of the planar code state as well, and we have to adjsut the stabilisers using the measurement results, but the overall state is still an eigenstate of those product logical operators.

Yes, you're correct.
